# Как залить на GithubPages несколько сайтов?

Tags: github-pages

Подскажите, пожалуйста, "на пальцах" начинающему разработчику. Хочу залить несколько сайтов на GHP. Везде пишут про создание поддиректорий. Но как создавать их я так и не понял. Можете пошагово объяснить как это делается?

Comment: Если нужно несколько независимых сайтов, то просто создайте отдельный репозиторий, и включите в нем github pages. Сайт из этого репозитория будет доступен по адресу `имя_пользователя.github.io/имя_репозитория`

Comment: При переходе выдает такую ошибку. 404
File not found

The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.                                      
   Может быть это связано с тем что у меня уже есть репозиторий  и он имеет такой же домен как и логин моего профиля? (Подключал по курсам Udemy Петриченко).

Comment: Все что угодно может быть. Начиная с невключенного github pages в настройках репозитория, до index.html как-то неправильно названного

Comment: Хотелось бы разобраться как это делать. Можете помочь?

Вариант 1

Использовать папки-поддиректории:

nickname.github.io - корневая директория сайта (главная страница)
nickname.github.io/site 1/ - поддиректория 1 (папка сайта 1)
nickname.github.io/site 2/ - поддиректория 2 (папка сайта 2)
nickname.github.io/site 3/ - поддиректория 3 (папка сайта 3)